# How can I print individual characters on pre-desktop system log screen in linux at first log message?

Tags: linux, logging

I want customize the booting to display a message character by character in the system log display that appears before the desktop login. If I make my own kernel module to do the printing, how can I load the module early in the boot process? In otherwords how can I do this without recompiling the kernel?

I'm using lubuntu.